# Specifying HasForeignKey with ModelBuilder?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Say I have a "Relationship" entity:

```
public class Relationship
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int RelationshipId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FriendOneId { get; set; }
    public virtual User FriendOne{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FriendTwoId { get; set; }
    public virtual User FriendTwo { get; set; }
}
```

If I want to map these relationships with ModelBuilder, what is the difference between this:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Relationship>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.FriendOne)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.FriendOneId);
```

And this:

```
       modelBuilder.Entity<Relationship>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.FriendOne)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.RelationshipId);
```

I get confused with this every time I'm setting up a new DB.  The documentation I've found and answers on SO seem to conflict one another on this... any help in understanding how to use HasForeignKey would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ThisT>()       //configure model for entity type <T>

.HasRequired(c => c.FriendOne)         // if a field, ef will create on DB as Not Null, and check in context  
                                       // if it is a navigation entity, then an underlying FK field will be marked as Not null .  
                                     // A new field will be introduce to manage this if not declared


    .WithMany()       // the target of foreign key can many Entity<t> pointing at it.
                      // The Many target could also have ICOllection<ThisT>.
                      // ie .withMany(MainT=>MainT.BucketOfThem) 
                     // leave it empty if the other side doesnt track related


    .HasForeignKey(u => u.RelationshipId); // dont create a field, I have one already..
                     // the Key to Table behind FriendOne is called RelationshipId
```

standard EF docu  on withMany  knows that call is chained.
ie first you a HasRequired, then a WithMany.
so you are in 1:M config mode.

```
/// <summary>
/// Configures the relationship to be required:many with a navigation property on the other side of the relationship.
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="navigationPropertyExpression">An lambda expression representing the navigation property on the other end of the relationship. C#: t =&gt; t.MyProperty VB.Net: Function(t) t.MyProperty </param>
/// <returns>
/// A configuration object that can be used to further configure the relationship.
/// </returns>
```

Comment: Thanks phil - "the Key to Table behind FriendOne is here" - what does that mean?

Comment: see edit - HASForeignKey means i have the FK field in my table, Use that please rather than creating an extra field