# Entity Framework : Lazy Loading Not working

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I am getting all the related tables populated (multiple times /circular/loop) even for a simple include of 2 tables query..

Here are my DB details.

```
public interface IPhaniDbContext
{
        DbSet<Data_CustomerDetail> CustomerDetails { get; set; }
        DbSet<Data_DisplayStyle> DisplayStyles { get; set; }
        DbSet<Data_ResumeDetail> ResumeDetails { get; set; }

        int Save();
        Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();

        Database Database { get; }

        DbEntityEntry Entity(object entity);

        DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
}

public class PhaniDbContext :DbContext , IPhaniDbContext
{
        public PhaniDbContext() : base(ConnectionString())
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

        private static string ConnectionString()
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.Appsetting_PhaniDbConnectionString];
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType()));

            modelBuilder.Entity<Data_CustomerDetail>()
                .HasMany(x => x.ResumeDetails).WithRequired(e => e.CustomerDetail).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            //modelBuilder.Entity<Data_CustomerDetail>()
            //    .Map(x => x.Requires("ResumeDetails")).Ignore(e => e.ResumeDetails)
            //    .Map(x => x.Requires("DisplayStyle")).Ignore(e => e.ResumeDetails);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Data_DisplayStyle>()
                .HasMany(x => x.ResumeDetails).WithRequired(e => e.DisplayStyle).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        }

        public int Save()
        {
            return  base.SaveChanges();
        }

        public DbEntityEntry Entity(object entity)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        //TODO: No-Urget-Over ride Save just to know. and all other possible overrides.
        public virtual DbSet<Data_CustomerDetail> CustomerDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Data_DisplayStyle> DisplayStyles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Data_ResumeDetail> ResumeDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Query:

```
 _phaniDbContext.CustomerDetails
                .Include(x => x.ResumeDetails)
                .Include(x=>x.ResumeDetails.Select(y=>y.DisplayStyle))
                .First(x=>x.CustomerDetailsID == customerId);
```

My pocos are here:

```
[Table("CustomerDetails")]
public class Data_CustomerDetail
{
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Data_CustomerDetail()
        {
            ResumeDetails = new HashSet<Data_ResumeDetail>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int CustomerDetailsID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string phoneNumber { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Zipcode { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Data_ResumeDetail> ResumeDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Data_DisplayStyle
{
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Data_DisplayStyle()
        {
            ResumeDetails = new HashSet<Data_ResumeDetail>();
        }

        public int DisplayStyleID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Data_ResumeDetail> ResumeDetails { get; set; }
}

[Table("ResumeDetails")]
public class Data_ResumeDetail
{
        [Key]
        public int ResumeDetailsId { get; set; }

        [Column("CAREER OBJECTIVE")]
        [StringLength(4000)]
        public string CAREER_OBJECTIVE { get; set; }

        [Column("HONORS AND REWARDS")]
        [StringLength(4000)]
        public string HONORS_AND_REWARDS { get; set; }

        [Column("PROFESSIONAL RESPONSIBILITIES")]
        [StringLength(4000)]
        public string PROFESSIONAL_RESPONSIBILITIES { get; set; }

        [Column("RELATED EXPERIENCE")]
        [StringLength(4000)]
        public string RELATED_EXPERIENCE { get; set; }

        public int? CustomerDetailsID { get; set; }

        public int? DisplayStyleId { get; set; }

        public virtual Data_CustomerDetail CustomerDetail { get; set; }

        public virtual Data_DisplayStyle DisplayStyle { get; set; }
}
```

Could someone please help me in resolving this...

I just want CustomerDetails and ResumeDetails and displaystyle table once... not multiple times..

This is increasing my object weight

Comment: You are wondering why lazy loading is not working but you added `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = True also loading in the same way..

Comment: You never used `.HasForeignKey(...)` or the `ForeignKey` attribute to tell EF how to relate the required entities. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920412/specifying-hasforeignkey-with-modelbuilder

Comment: I just used all the relations that are generated with code first for existing DataBase template. Also,I tried HasForeignKey but i am getting errors: Could you please help me in formulating them.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a foreign key relationship, you probably need to specify the foreign key(s)

Example:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Data_CustomerDetail>()
    .HasMany(x => x.ResumeDetails)
    .WithRequired(e => e.CustomerDetail)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.CustomerDetailsID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder
    .Entity<Data_DisplayStyle>()
    .HasMany(x => x.ResumeDetails)
    .WithRequired(e => e.DisplayStyle)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.DisplayStyleId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Even with the foriegn key i am getting huge data.   my  code is in git hub https://github.com/pavankumar0425/PhaniResumeAPi .. hope it helps to identify the issue.